# How to fix mouse slow sensitivity in Minecraft Java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mouse

I have a problem with my mouse control since yesterday. When I move my mouse the screen moves slowly like a movie animation. I don't know what to do. I clicked every buttons in Minecraft. Do I need to reinstall? How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that can fix this problem.
First, check if you have enabled Minecraft's cinematic camera, you can find its hotkey in Minecraft control settings.
If this is not, maybe you have to change the mouse sensitivity in Minecraft mouse settings.

Comment: thanks. it was  cinematic camera.